# Different behaviors when copying the same Tensorflow loss function to Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Since Keras is using tensorflow as backend, in theory we can use tensorflow operations such as `tf.logical_not`, `tf.eye`, `tf.diag_part` in keras, aren't we?

I saw a triplet online mining implementation in tensorflow [here](https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss), and I would like to use it with keras instead. So I just copy the loss function written in tensorflow to keras loss function as shown below:

```
def batch_hard_triplet_loss(margin=1, squared=False):
    """Build the triplet loss over a batch of embeddings.

    For each anchor, we get the hardest positive and hardest negative to form a triplet.

    Args:
        labels: labels of the batch, of size (batch_size,)
        embeddings: tensor of shape (batch_size, embed_dim)
        margin: margin for triplet loss
        squared: Boolean. If true, output is the pairwise squared euclidean distance matrix.
                 If false, output is the pairwise euclidean distance matrix.

    Returns:
        triplet_loss: scalar tensor containing the triplet loss
    """
    def loss(labels, embeddings):
        # Get the pairwise distance matrix
        pairwise_dist = _pairwise_distances(embeddings, squared=squared)

        # For each anchor, get the hardest positive
        # First, we need to get a mask for every valid positive (they should have same label)
        mask_anchor_positive = _get_anchor_positive_triplet_mask(labels)
        mask_anchor_positive = tf.to_float(mask_anchor_positive)

        # We put to 0 any element where (a, p) is not valid (valid if a != p and label(a) == label(p))
        anchor_positive_dist = tf.multiply(mask_anchor_positive, pairwise_dist)

        # shape (batch_size, 1)
        hardest_positive_dist = tf.reduce_max(anchor_positive_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        tf.summary.scalar("hardest_positive_dist", tf.reduce_mean(hardest_positive_dist))

        # For each anchor, get the hardest negative
        # First, we need to get a mask for every valid negative (they should have different labels)
        mask_anchor_negative = _get_anchor_negative_triplet_mask(labels)
        mask_anchor_negative = tf.to_float(mask_anchor_negative)

        # We add the maximum value in each row to the invalid negatives (label(a) == label(n))
        max_anchor_negative_dist = tf.reduce_max(pairwise_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        anchor_negative_dist = pairwise_dist + max_anchor_negative_dist * (1.0 - mask_anchor_negative)

        # shape (batch_size,)
        hardest_negative_dist = tf.reduce_min(anchor_negative_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        tf.summary.scalar("hardest_negative_dist", tf.reduce_mean(hardest_negative_dist))

        # Combine biggest d(a, p) and smallest d(a, n) into final triplet loss
        triplet_loss = tf.maximum(hardest_positive_dist - hardest_negative_dist + margin, 0.0)

        # Get final mean triplet loss
        triplet_loss = tf.reduce_mean(triplet_loss)

        return triplet_loss
    return loss
```

Then I compile my Keras model like this

```
model.compile(loss=batch_hard_triplet_loss(margin=1, squared=False), optimizer=adam_optim)
```

The model underwent training successfully, but cluster is wrong.
[image]

Now, if I train with the original tensorflow code, I get the following cluster instead, which is correct:
[image]

There's essentially no difference between the two model, but how do they give a different result? The only thing I am not sure is whether mixing tensorflow operations such as `tf.matmal`  with keras will cause any problem. Other than this, I cannot think of any cause to the difference.

### My full Keras code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import random
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Lambda, Dense, Flatten,MaxPooling2D, concatenate
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
import os
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from itertools import permutations
import seaborn as sns
from keras.datasets import mnist
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
def scatter(x, labels, subtitle=None):
    num_class = len(set(labels))

    # We choose a color palette with seaborn.
    palette = np.array(sns.color_palette("hls", 10))

    # We create a scatter plot.
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    ax = plt.subplot(aspect='equal')
    sc = ax.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], lw=0, s=40,
                    c=palette[labels.astype(np.int)])
    plt.xlim(-25, 25)
    plt.ylim(-25, 25)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.axis('tight')

    # We add the labels for each digit.
    txts = []
    for i in range(num_class):
        # Position of each label.
        xtext, ytext = np.median(x[labels == i, :], axis=0)
        txt = ax.text(xtext, ytext, str(i), fontsize=24)
        txt.set_path_effects([
            PathEffects.Stroke(linewidth=5, foreground="w"),
            PathEffects.Normal()])
        txts.append(txt)

    if subtitle != None:
        plt.suptitle(subtitle)

#     plt.savefig(subtitle)


# In[9]:


x_train_flat = x_train.reshape(-1,784)
x_test_flat = x_test.reshape(-1,784)


# In[10]:


tsne = TSNE()
train_tsne_embeds = tsne.fit_transform(x_train_flat[:512])
scatter(train_tsne_embeds, y_train[:512], "Samples from Training Data")

eval_tsne_embeds = tsne.fit_transform(x_test_flat[:512])
scatter(eval_tsne_embeds, y_test[:512], "Samples from Validation Data")

def _get_triplet_mask(labels):
    """Return a 3D mask where mask[a, p, n] is True iff the triplet (a, p, n) is valid.

    A triplet (i, j, k) is valid if:
        - i, j, k are distinct
        - labels[i] == labels[j] and labels[i] != labels[k]

    Args:
        labels: tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size]
    """
    # Check that i, j and k are distinct
    indices_equal = tf.cast(tf.eye(tf.shape(labels)[0]), tf.bool)
    indices_not_equal = tf.logical_not(indices_equal)
    i_not_equal_j = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 2)
    i_not_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 1)
    j_not_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 0)

    distinct_indices = tf.logical_and(tf.logical_and(i_not_equal_j, i_not_equal_k), j_not_equal_k)


    # Check if labels[i] == labels[j] and labels[i] != labels[k]
    label_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))
    i_equal_j = tf.expand_dims(label_equal, 2)
    i_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(label_equal, 1)

    valid_labels = tf.logical_and(i_equal_j, tf.logical_not(i_equal_k))

    # Combine the two masks
    mask = tf.logical_and(distinct_indices, valid_labels)

    return mask


def _get_anchor_positive_triplet_mask(labels):
    """Return a 2D mask where mask[a, p] is True iff a and p are distinct and have same label.

    Args:
        labels: tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size]

    Returns:
        mask: tf.bool `Tensor` with shape [batch_size, batch_size]
    """
    # Check that i and j are distinct
    indices_equal = tf.cast(tf.eye(tf.shape(labels)[0]), tf.bool)
    indices_not_equal = tf.logical_not(indices_equal)

    # Check if labels[i] == labels[j]
    # Uses broadcasting where the 1st argument has shape (1, batch_size) and the 2nd (batch_size, 1)
    labels_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))

    # Combine the two masks
    mask = tf.logical_and(indices_not_equal, labels_equal)

    return mask


def _get_anchor_negative_triplet_mask(labels):
    """Return a 2D mask where mask[a, n] is True iff a and n have distinct labels.

    Args:
        labels: tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size]

    Returns:
        mask: tf.bool `Tensor` with shape [batch_size, batch_size]
    """
    # Check if labels[i] != labels[k]
    # Uses broadcasting where the 1st argument has shape (1, batch_size) and the 2nd (batch_size, 1)
    labels_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))

    mask = tf.logical_not(labels_equal)

    return mask


def _pairwise_distances(embeddings, squared=False):
    """Compute the 2D matrix of distances between all the embeddings.

    Args:
        embeddings: tensor of shape (batch_size, embed_dim)
        squared: Boolean. If true, output is the pairwise squared euclidean distance matrix.
                 If false, output is the pairwise euclidean distance matrix.

    Returns:
        pairwise_distances: tensor of shape (batch_size, batch_size)
    """
    # Get the dot product between all embeddings
    # shape (batch_size, batch_size)
    dot_product = tf.matmul(embeddings, tf.transpose(embeddings))

    # Get squared L2 norm for each embedding. We can just take the diagonal of `dot_product`.
    # This also provides more numerical stability (the diagonal of the result will be exactly 0).
    # shape (batch_size,)
    square_norm = tf.diag_part(dot_product)

    # Compute the pairwise distance matrix as we have:
    # ||a - b||^2 = ||a||^2  - 2 <a, b> + ||b||^2
    # shape (batch_size, batch_size)
    distances = tf.expand_dims(square_norm, 1) - 2.0 * dot_product + tf.expand_dims(square_norm, 0)

    # Because of computation errors, some distances might be negative so we put everything >= 0.0
    distances = tf.maximum(distances, 0.0)

    if not squared:
        # Because the gradient of sqrt is infinite when distances == 0.0 (ex: on the diagonal)
        # we need to add a small epsilon where distances == 0.0
        mask = tf.to_float(tf.equal(distances, 0.0))
        distances = distances + mask * 1e-16

        distances = tf.sqrt(distances)

        # Correct the epsilon added: set the distances on the mask to be exactly 0.0
        distances = distances * (1.0 - mask)

    return distances

def batch_hard_triplet_loss(margin=1, squared=False):
    """Build the triplet loss over a batch of embeddings.

    For each anchor, we get the hardest positive and hardest negative to form a triplet.

    Args:
        labels: labels of the batch, of size (batch_size,)
        embeddings: tensor of shape (batch_size, embed_dim)
        margin: margin for triplet loss
        squared: Boolean. If true, output is the pairwise squared euclidean distance matrix.
                 If false, output is the pairwise euclidean distance matrix.

    Returns:
        triplet_loss: scalar tensor containing the triplet loss
    """
    def loss(labels, embeddings):
        # Get the pairwise distance matrix
        pairwise_dist = _pairwise_distances(embeddings, squared=squared)

        # For each anchor, get the hardest positive
        # First, we need to get a mask for every valid positive (they should have same label)
        mask_anchor_positive = _get_anchor_positive_triplet_mask(labels)
        mask_anchor_positive = tf.to_float(mask_anchor_positive)

        # We put to 0 any element where (a, p) is not valid (valid if a != p and label(a) == label(p))
        anchor_positive_dist = tf.multiply(mask_anchor_positive, pairwise_dist)

        # shape (batch_size, 1)
        hardest_positive_dist = tf.reduce_max(anchor_positive_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        tf.summary.scalar("hardest_positive_dist", tf.reduce_mean(hardest_positive_dist))

        # For each anchor, get the hardest negative
        # First, we need to get a mask for every valid negative (they should have different labels)
        mask_anchor_negative = _get_anchor_negative_triplet_mask(labels)
        mask_anchor_negative = tf.to_float(mask_anchor_negative)

        # We add the maximum value in each row to the invalid negatives (label(a) == label(n))
        max_anchor_negative_dist = tf.reduce_max(pairwise_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        anchor_negative_dist = pairwise_dist + max_anchor_negative_dist * (1.0 - mask_anchor_negative)

        # shape (batch_size,)
        hardest_negative_dist = tf.reduce_min(anchor_negative_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        tf.summary.scalar("hardest_negative_dist", tf.reduce_mean(hardest_negative_dist))

        # Combine biggest d(a, p) and smallest d(a, n) into final triplet loss
        triplet_loss = tf.maximum(hardest_positive_dist - hardest_negative_dist + margin, 0.0)

        # Get final mean triplet loss
        triplet_loss = tf.reduce_mean(triplet_loss)

        return triplet_loss
    return loss

def create_base_network(in_dims):
    """
    Base network to be shared.
    """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(7,7),padding='same',input_shape=(in_dims[0],in_dims[1],in_dims[2],),activation='relu',name='conv1'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),(2,2),padding='same',name='pool1'))
    model.add(Conv2D(256,(5,5),padding='same',activation='relu',name='conv2'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),(2,2),padding='same',name='pool2'))
    model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
    model.add(Dense(4,name='embeddings'))
    # model.add(Dense(600))

    return model

adam_optim = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)


# In[14]:


input_layer = Input((28,28,1, ), name='input')

# Shared embedding layer for positive and negative items
Shared_DNN = create_base_network([28,28,1,])

embeddings = Shared_DNN(input_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=embeddings)
model.compile(loss=batch_hard_triplet_loss(margin=1, squared=False), optimizer=adam_optim)

model.fit(np.expand_dims(x_train,-1),y=y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=2)

tsne = TSNE()
X_train_trm = model.predict(x_train.reshape(-1,28,28,1))
X_test_trm = model.predict(x_test.reshape(-1,28,28,1))
train_tsne_embeds = tsne.fit_transform(X_train_trm[:512])
eval_tsne_embeds = tsne.fit_transform(X_test_trm[:512])
# train_tsne_embeds = X_train_trm[:512]
# eval_tsne_embeds = X_test_trm[:512]

# In[22]:


scatter(train_tsne_embeds, y_train[:512], "Training Data After TNN")
```

### My full tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

def scatter(x, labels, subtitle=None):
    num_class = len(set(labels))

    # We choose a color palette with seaborn.
    palette = np.array(sns.color_palette("hls", 10))

    # We create a scatter plot.
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    ax = plt.subplot(aspect='equal')
    sc = ax.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], lw=0, s=40,
                    c=palette[labels.astype(np.int)])
    plt.xlim(-25, 25)
    plt.ylim(-25, 25)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.axis('tight')

    # We add the labels for each digit.
    txts = []
    for i in range(num_class):
        # Position of each label.
        xtext, ytext = np.median(x[labels == i, :], axis=0)
        txt = ax.text(xtext, ytext, str(i), fontsize=24)
        txt.set_path_effects([
            PathEffects.Stroke(linewidth=5, foreground="w"),
            PathEffects.Normal()])
        txts.append(txt)

    if subtitle != None:
        plt.suptitle(subtitle)

    plt.savefig(subtitle)

"""Define functions to create the triplet loss with online triplet mining."""
def _pairwise_distances(embeddings, squared=False):
    """Compute the 2D matrix of distances between all the embeddings.
    Args:
        embeddings: tensor of shape (batch_size, embed_dim)
        squared: Boolean. If true, output is the pairwise squared euclidean distance matrix.
                 If false, output is the pairwise euclidean distance matrix.
    Returns:
        pairwise_distances: tensor of shape (batch_size, batch_size)
    """
    # Get the dot product between all embeddings
    # shape (batch_size, batch_size)
    dot_product = tf.matmul(embeddings, tf.transpose(embeddings))

    # Get squared L2 norm for each embedding. We can just take the diagonal of `dot_product`.
    # This also provides more numerical stability (the diagonal of the result will be exactly 0).
    # shape (batch_size,)
    square_norm = tf.diag_part(dot_product)

    # Compute the pairwise distance matrix as we have:
    # ||a - b||^2 = ||a||^2  - 2 <a, b> + ||b||^2
    # shape (batch_size, batch_size)
    distances = tf.expand_dims(square_norm, 1) - 2.0 * dot_product + tf.expand_dims(square_norm, 0)

    # Because of computation errors, some distances might be negative so we put everything >= 0.0
    distances = tf.maximum(distances, 0.0)

    if not squared:
        # Because the gradient of sqrt is infinite when distances == 0.0 (ex: on the diagonal)
        # we need to add a small epsilon where distances == 0.0
        mask = tf.to_float(tf.equal(distances, 0.0))
        distances = distances + mask * 1e-16

        distances = tf.sqrt(distances)

        # Correct the epsilon added: set the distances on the mask to be exactly 0.0
        distances = distances * (1.0 - mask)

    return distances


def _get_anchor_positive_triplet_mask(labels):
    """Return a 2D mask where mask[a, p] is True iff a and p are distinct and have same label.
    Args:
        labels: tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size]
    Returns:
        mask: tf.bool `Tensor` with shape [batch_size, batch_size]
    """
    # Check that i and j are distinct
    indices_equal = tf.cast(tf.eye(tf.shape(labels)[0]), tf.bool)
    indices_not_equal = tf.logical_not(indices_equal)

    # Check if labels[i] == labels[j]
    # Uses broadcasting where the 1st argument has shape (1, batch_size) and the 2nd (batch_size, 1)
    labels_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))

    # Combine the two masks
    mask = tf.logical_and(indices_not_equal, labels_equal)

    return mask


def _get_anchor_negative_triplet_mask(labels):
    """Return a 2D mask where mask[a, n] is True iff a and n have distinct labels.
    Args:
        labels: tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size]
    Returns:
        mask: tf.bool `Tensor` with shape [batch_size, batch_size]
    """
    # Check if labels[i] != labels[k]
    # Uses broadcasting where the 1st argument has shape (1, batch_size) and the 2nd (batch_size, 1)
    labels_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))

    mask = tf.logical_not(labels_equal)

    return mask


def _get_triplet_mask(labels):
    """Return a 3D mask where mask[a, p, n] is True iff the triplet (a, p, n) is valid.
    A triplet (i, j, k) is valid if:
        - i, j, k are distinct
        - labels[i] == labels[j] and labels[i] != labels[k]
    Args:
        labels: tf.int32 `Tensor` with shape [batch_size]
    """
    # Check that i, j and k are distinct
    indices_equal = tf.cast(tf.eye(tf.shape(labels)[0]), tf.bool)
    indices_not_equal = tf.logical_not(indices_equal)
    i_not_equal_j = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 2)
    i_not_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 1)
    j_not_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(indices_not_equal, 0)

    distinct_indices = tf.logical_and(tf.logical_and(i_not_equal_j, i_not_equal_k), j_not_equal_k)


    # Check if labels[i] == labels[j] and labels[i] != labels[k]
    label_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))
    i_equal_j = tf.expand_dims(label_equal, 2)
    i_equal_k = tf.expand_dims(label_equal, 1)

    valid_labels = tf.logical_and(i_equal_j, tf.logical_not(i_equal_k))

    # Combine the two masks
    mask = tf.logical_and(distinct_indices, valid_labels)

    return mask

def batch_hard_triplet_loss(labels, embeddings, margin, squared=False):
    """Build the triplet loss over a batch of embeddings.
    For each anchor, we get the hardest positive and hardest negative to form a triplet.
    Args:
        labels: labels of the batch, of size (batch_size,)
        embeddings: tensor of shape (batch_size, embed_dim)
        margin: margin for triplet loss
        squared: Boolean. If true, output is the pairwise squared euclidean distance matrix.
                 If false, output is the pairwise euclidean distance matrix.
    Returns:
        triplet_loss: scalar tensor containing the triplet loss
    """
    # Get the pairwise distance matrix
    pairwise_dist = _pairwise_distances(embeddings, squared=squared)

    # For each anchor, get the hardest positive
    # First, we need to get a mask for every valid positive (they should have same label)
    mask_anchor_positive = _get_anchor_positive_triplet_mask(labels)
    mask_anchor_positive = tf.to_float(mask_anchor_positive)

    # We put to 0 any element where (a, p) is not valid (valid if a != p and label(a) == label(p))
    anchor_positive_dist = tf.multiply(mask_anchor_positive, pairwise_dist)

    # shape (batch_size, 1)
    hardest_positive_dist = tf.reduce_max(anchor_positive_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    tf.summary.scalar("hardest_positive_dist", tf.reduce_mean(hardest_positive_dist))

    # For each anchor, get the hardest negative
    # First, we need to get a mask for every valid negative (they should have different labels)
    mask_anchor_negative = _get_anchor_negative_triplet_mask(labels)
    mask_anchor_negative = tf.to_float(mask_anchor_negative)

    # We add the maximum value in each row to the invalid negatives (label(a) == label(n))
    max_anchor_negative_dist = tf.reduce_max(pairwise_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    anchor_negative_dist = pairwise_dist + max_anchor_negative_dist * (1.0 - mask_anchor_negative)

    # shape (batch_size,)
    hardest_negative_dist = tf.reduce_min(anchor_negative_dist, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    tf.summary.scalar("hardest_negative_dist", tf.reduce_mean(hardest_negative_dist))

    # Combine biggest d(a, p) and smallest d(a, n) into final triplet loss
    triplet_loss = tf.maximum(hardest_positive_dist - hardest_negative_dist + margin, 0.0)

    # Get final mean triplet loss
    triplet_loss = tf.reduce_mean(triplet_loss)

    return triplet_loss

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    """Model function for CNN."""
    # Input Layer
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Convolutional Layer #1
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=128,
      kernel_size=[7, 7],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

    # Pooling Layer #1
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

    # Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=256,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)



    # Dense Layer
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 256])
    embeddings = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=4, activation=None)


    predictions = {'embeddings' :pool2_flat}

#     dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
#     dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
#       inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

#     # Logits Layer
#     logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

#     predictions = {
#       # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
#       "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
#       # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
#       # `logging_hook`.
#       "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
#     }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

    # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
    loss = batch_hard_triplet_loss(labels, embeddings, margin=1,squared=False)

    # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

((x_train, y_train),
 (x_test, y_test)) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train/np.float32(255)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int32)  # not required

x_test = x_test/np.float32(255)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)

mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir='./hardmine/')

tensors_to_log = {}

logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
    tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

# Define data loader
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_train},
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=128,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

# train one step and display the probabilties
mnist_classifier.train(
    input_fn=train_input_fn,
    steps=900,
    hooks=[logging_hook])

train_input_fn_512 = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_train[:512]},
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

train_embedding = mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=train_input_fn_512)

predict = []
for i in train_embedding:
    predict.append(i['embeddings'])
predict = np.array(predict)

tsne = TSNE()

train_tsne_embeds = tsne.fit_transform(predict[:512])
# eval_tsne_embeds = tsne.fit_transform(X_test_trm[:512])
# train_tsne_embeds = X_train_trm[:512]
# eval_tsne_embeds = X_test_trm[:512]

# In[22]:

scatter(train_tsne_embeds, y_train[:512], "Training Data After TNN")
```

Comment: I think this is not very likely to be the issue, but one minor difference is that the `epsilon` parameter to the Adam optimizer, left as default in both cases, appears to be `1e-7` for Keras and `1e-8` for TensorFlow.

Comment: I have changed the keras epsilon to `1e-8` by using the command `K.set_epsilon(1e-8)`, and ran a quick test. The cluster learned by keras is still wrong. So epsilon is not the issue.